# Restsharp Picnob Response as forbidden

Tags: c#, request, response, restsharp

I am trying to download html from website picnob.com, When I request using POSTMAN it gives full html. But when I do same with my c# code it gives "forbidden" error.

Below is postman code which I am using

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.picnob.com/");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "6bb5dfa4-6097-e628-8b6c-4dd814ac2e8d");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

When I saw HTML if response it says "Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue".
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: RestSharp is built for calling APIs, not load webpages.

Comment: Then what can i use for loading webpages ?